# No delegates were triggered if app is in backgroundmode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, restkit

I am at the beginning with RestKit-development. I develop an app that
get data from a Server and map these in objects. With a trick of
silence music, is it possible to send request to the backend, if the
app is in background mode . If I
leave the app the request will send, but the delegate of "finish with
objectmapping"  will not throw, but if I start (activate the app) the
app, the delegates
will fire. Is  there are a way, to map the json if the app is in
background mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've provided an answer to your other post which I think will help you here.  See link:

[Your other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519664/no-request-will-send-if-app-is-in-background-mode-optionen/8522853#8522853)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you configure your application to have a background mode that plays music and play audio while you want your application to continue to run.  You can use a silent audio file if you don't actually want to play music so long as you don't want to distribute it through the App Store, but Apple will not approve it for the App Store unless there is actual music as an actual feature in your application.

Comment: Ok I play an silent audio, so that the app running in background mode, so there is no other opportunity to run it continue und refresh the data. :( So the app will no approved, you say