# No Request will send if app is in background mode Optionen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, restkit

With a trick it is possible to run the app, if the home button is 
pressed. In the background mode, no request with RKRequestQueue will 
be send, so the app receive no response from backande server and the 
app can't update the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard behavior.  When the app becomes active (i.e. is running and no longer in the background), you may want to implement the `-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIAplication *)application` method in your application delegate which would resume where you left off, or to resubmit your request, restart your request queue, whatever your situation requires.